# Admin Page Sidebar Re-Order

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to re-order the left side bar menu in the admin page.

I am running [VneComms V-Admin Theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/v-admin.html)

Below is how is currently looks. I would like to re-order the headings. For example, put 'General' at the top.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Admin Page Left Side Bar Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the order of the tabs in the configuration panel is determined by the sort orders of the `tab` nodes from all the `system.xml` files from all the modules.
Usually, `general` is the first tab, but apparently you have an extension cookie consent or something like that that decided to add it's own tab above all.
Look in your code for the text "Mnts Infotech" in the files called `system.xml` and change the sort order tag of the `tab` tag that contains that text. The bigger the value, the lower it will be in the menu.

Comment: Wow, thats a bit long winded. Shame there isnt a single file. Works though! Thanks!